# Android: Метод для виджета

Tags: android, java

Пишу виджет, и у меня появилась такая проблема.

Есть метод onEnabied() - он вызывается при создании первого экземпляра виджета.
А мне нужен метод,который вызывается при создании любого (всех последующих) экземпляров.

Мне судя по всему не подходит **onUpdate()**.
У меня такая задача: при создании виджета вынести список с файлами для выбора тестового файла, который будет открываться виджетом.
Виджетов может быть несколько,с разными путями до файлов файлов и т.п.

И ещё: где для данной цели лучше хранить путь к файлу?
В переменной, SharedPreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно после определённого действия с виджетом, как то его видоизменить? 
Если так, то мне кажется, что как раз таки нужен onUpdate().

Вот пример:

```
public class widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
        private PendingIntent pendingIntentService;

        public void onUpdate(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {

                //привязываем севис к клику
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
                Intent service = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
                pendingIntentService = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, service, 0);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1, pendingIntentService);
            }

        public static class UpdateService extends Service {
                @Override
                public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                          super.onStart(intent, startId);

                        RemoteViews updateViews = textupdate(this);
                        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, widget.class);
                        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
                        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
                }
                @Override
                        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return null;
                        }
     }

        public static RemoteViews textupdate(Context context) {
                 RemoteViews updateViews = null;
                 updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                 String quote = "Widget Hello"
                 final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);   
                    db.open();
                    quote = db.getRandomEntry();  
                    db.close();

        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.testtext, quote);
       return updateViews;     
     }
}
```

Так я менял текст у себя в виджете.

P.S. Если я неправильно понял, то объясни по подробней, может смогу, чем то помочь.